# Geofence compile error

Tags: java, android, android-geofence, geofire

I keep getting this error in android studio how do I fix this?

here's my code:

```
  dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.h6ah4i.android.widget.verticalseekbar:verticalseekbar:0.7.2'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:geofire-android:2.1.2'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:10.2.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:10.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    //compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:10.2.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:10.2.0'



    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

---

```
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.0'
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'
```

Error is:

> Error:(40, 0) Version: 2.1.2 is lower than the minimum version (9.0.0)
>   required for google-services plugin. Open
>   File